# Non-conditional probability to be in a given state in a markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-process

I am asking your help for a question I couldn't find the answer on the internet.

I am considering a markov chain with 3 states. The transition probability matrix is pij, i, j from 1 to 3. pij is the probability for the markov chain to be in state i at time t knowing it is in state j at time t-1.

I'm a looking for the non conditional probability: P(state in t=j).

I know the formula in the case where there are 2 states, but I can't find a general formula, for n states (3 states in my case). I guess I found the answer in some academic articles, but I don't understand it and how to apply it.

Comment: Unconditional probabilities like this are expressable as a two-way contingency table (with 3 levels or states) based on the current status at time, *t*, classified against the object's status at time *t-1*, summarized across all time periods, *T*, as *t* vs *t-1*, *t-1* vs *t-2*, *t-2* vs *t-3*, and so on. Obviously, this can easily be written as a formula but for the fact that I don't know the CV version of Latex. There is a wide literature on this. So, I'll leave it as a comment. One additional note, log-linear models would provide a functional form for expressing conditional probabilities.

Comment: There is no unique definition for an _unconditional_ probability: do you mean, e.g., the stationary distribution?

Comment: Making two identical rows in the transition matrix, indicates it doesn't matter which of two states was visited last. A Markov chain does not require 'one step' dependence, a completely independent process is Markovian (but, if so, perhaps the extra notation is then not worth the trouble)

Answer (score 2):

**The answer depends on the probabilities of the initial state.**

You can work it out from [basic axioms of probability.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms)  It's helpful as well as insightful to use matrix notation, but *you only need to know two things about matrices:* how to multiply them and the fact that multiplication is associative.  Specifically, when $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector and $\mathbb{A},\mathbb{B}$ are matrices, then $$(\mathbf{x}\mathbb{A})\mathbb{B} = \mathbf{x}(\mathbb A \mathbb B)$$ whenever either expression is defined.

Let the initial state correspond to time $t=0.$  At any time $t\ge 0$ let the unconditional probability of state $j$ be $p_t(j),$ forming a row vector $\mathbf{p}_t$ with one component for each state in the set of all states $S.$  At time $t\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ the answer in terms of the transition matrix 
$$\mathbb{P} = (p_{ij})$$ is

> $$\mathbf{p}_t =  \mathbf{p}_0\mathbb{P}^t.$$

These matrix powers are defined recursively as

$$\mathbb{P}^0 = \mathbb{I}_S$$

(the identity matrix on the states $S$) and

$$\mathbb{P}^t = \mathbb{P}^{t-1}\mathbb{P}$$

for $t=1,2,3,\ldots.$

Because $\mathbb{P}^0$ is defined to be the identity matrix, the formula is true at $t=0.$  Suppose inductively that this formula is still correct at some arbitrary time $t-1.$  We need only show it will then be correct at time $t.$

To this end, decompose the event $\mathcal{P}_{t}(j):$ "the system is in state $j$ at time $t$" into a union of events of the form $\mathcal{P}_t(i\to j):$ "the system made a transition from state $i$ to state $j$ at time $t$" where $i$ ranges over all the states.

Being a Markov chain means these transitions are independent of the probabilities of their starting states, and [independence only means *the probabilities multiply:*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_events)

$$\Pr(\mathcal{P}_t(i\to j)) = p_{t-1}(i)\, p_{ij}.$$

Because these transitions all start from different states, they have nothing in common.  Thus, it is axiomatic that *their probabilities add,* giving

$$p_t(j) = \Pr(\mathcal{P}_{t}(j)) = \sum_{i\in S} \Pr(\mathcal{P}_{t}(i\to j))  =  \sum_{i\in S} p_{t-1}(i)\, p_{ij}.$$

But that sum merely expresses the law of matrix multiplication when computing $\mathbf{p}_{t-1}$ times $\mathbb{P},$ and so can be written in vector form as

$$\mathbf{p}_t = \mathbf{p}_{t-1}\,\mathbb{P} =  \left(\mathbf{p}_{0}\,\mathbb{P}^{t-1}\right)\mathbb{P} =  \mathbf{p}_{0}\left(\mathbb{P}^{t-1}\mathbb{P}\right) = \mathbf{p}_{0}\,\mathbb{P}^t$$

as claimed, *QED.*

---

**For example,** suppose the transition matrix is $$\mathbb{P} = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 1}.$$

Then you can work out that

$$\mathbb{P}^t = 2^{-t}\pmatrix{1 & t & 2^t-t-1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2^t-1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2^t}.$$

If, say, all states are equally likely initially, that means $$\mathbf{p}_0 = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{3}, & \frac{1}{3}, & \frac{1}{3} }$$

and therefore the chances at time $t$ are

$$\mathbf{p}_t = 2^{-t} \pmatrix{\frac{1}{3}, & \frac{1}{3}, & \frac{1}{3} } \pmatrix{1 & t & 2^t-t-1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2^t-1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2^t} = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{3\,2^t}, & \frac{1+t}{3\,2^t}, & 1 - \frac{2+t}{3\,2^t} }.$$

---

Wikipedia has an example in [its article on Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Example) with links to [an entire article on Markov chain examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_Markov_chains).